# Is there a word for incorrect use of capital letters?

Tags: capitalization

I'm wondering if there is a word for the wrong use of capital letters?

As in "The Little Girl was wearing a Red Dress" (not as a headline).

Is there a word for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would call it **miscapitalization**.

You can say a sentence or word is *miscapitalized*, just as you can say that a sentence is *mispunctuated*, or that a word is *misused*.

Answer (score 1):

The word used to describe the correct use of capitalization is orthography.  A misuse might be considered poor orthography.

Comment: We really say spelling in English.

Comment: Good suggestion! Please add a dictionary definition of 'orthography' in case someone isn't sure of the definition.

Answer (score -1):

If capital letters are used to  emphasize a word or a concept it could be seen as a [poetic license](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poetic+license).

> - The liberty taken by an artist or a writer in deviating from conventional form or fact to achieve a desired effect. (AHD)

The Free Dictionary